# What happens to your google account and google project when the email associated with the google account is deleted

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I have a dialogflow project (gcp project) on a google account associated with my work email (non gmail). What would happen to my account if I disable and delete my work email. Will I still be able to sign into the dialogflow project

Answer (score 0):

Seems that [this link](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/close-account#cancel_google_cloud) helps.

You can't use account associated GCP project anymore after deleting account.

If you want the project to be available with other users, so your dialflow still be able to use, grant owner role at project level to him/her.

Comment: Hey, the link says that canceling a google account will cancel your access to GCP projects but if we deactivate the email associated with the google account, we can still access the google account. How should I setup that relationship that if the email address associated with a google account is deleted then the google account also gets deleted

Comment: If you sure that google account is still available, You can access dialog project even when your work email is deleted. You need to close your google account manually if you want to delete it.